# Significance for the whole dataset of detections in a subsample

Tags: statistical-significance, sample, subset, subsampling

I have a fairly simple question, but I am not so familiar with these problems so I would like to ask.

If I have, let's say, 4 data samples belonging to the same overall population. If in a test a given property is detected independently in 2 of these samples with 3 sigma and 4 sigma significance, what is the significance of such detection in the whole population?

My answer would be that the only way to know is to repeat the test on the whole population, but I would like to know if it is possible to scale the result from the 2 samples detection, even if only to obtain a rough estimate, and in case how.

---

I'll try to explain myself with an example:

Let's say I have 4 independent spectra acquired from the same experimental setup. In 2 of them I detect an emission line from iron with the significances described above, and in the other 2 spectra I detect nothing.

Is there a way to determine the significance of the line detection in the whole dataset?

Comment: Without any context or examples, your question is difficult to understand.  Could you explain what it means to "detect ... a given property ... with 3 and 4 sigma significance," as well as what "such detection in the whole population" might mean?